# Q: Is this a Critic badge bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I got Critic badge yesterday, but My user page > Activity > votes > downvote say "you have not cast any votes". It seems strange, so I report it. I have something likely come to mind. After I voted up for someone's question (maybe from 1 to 2 votes), I wondered I'd voted him before and did vote-down to cancel it. But I surprised because of two down by one click and I hastily did vote-up again (0 to 2). This is all I remember. Is this a bug ?

[Additional Information]
I found this is the reproducible problem. In this meta community, I've done vote-up and subsequently tried to do vote-down. The System prevented me from doing vote-down (i.e., I failed to do vote-down), but I got Critic badge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have downvoted a few times - sure, you then *changed* the votes to be upvotes, but the system recorded those downvotes, making you eligible for the badge.

Comment: There is absolutely no objections to your opinion. I worry about counting an action not be realized . For example, If I voted my own question, I might have got Supporter badge.

Comment: You can't vote your own question. Also - this isn't opinion - I checked (I am a developer at Stack Exchange - I have access to all things...).

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed additional tag. I was relieved to hear that it's in the specifications. Thank you for your support !!